# Why literal value preceded by a string + colon character is not throwing runtime exception

Tags: javascript

I typed in the below expression by mistake and I am very surprised that it does not throw any runtime error

`some_text:true`

For example, I would rather expect something like:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: some_text:true is not defined*

Instead the expression just returns the literal value (true in the above example).
To generalize, any literal values (except object) preceded by a characters and ending with colon seem to be valid expression statement:

- some_text:1 --> 1
- some_text:"lorem" --> "lorem"

Comment: [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#labeled_statement)

Comment: It's not an *expression*. `(some_text:1)` is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An identifier followed by a colon creates a label.

This can be used with a number of statements, eg. to break out multiple levels of looping.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label